# Views - Filter "Content: Authored by" to show only content by anonymous users

Tags: 8, views

When filtering content in Views using the filter **Content: Authored by**, you get these choices:

[image: views authored by]

For the username, I typed "Anonymous", which gave me the UID of 0.

However, when I click **Apply (All Displays)**, I get this error:

`There are no entities matching "(0)".`

Is there a way to filter a view in Drupal 8 to only show content posted by anonymous users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter by User ID, is equal to 0.

[image]

[image]